# Allow page layout to hide control on master page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

If I want to use my regular master page for a new page layout, except I don't want the main navigation menu control (a 3rd party control) to be visible, how can I let the page layout hide it? In asp.net I would expose a public property or method on the master page and then call it from the child page, but not sure what can be done in SharePoint since there is no code behind or discernible master page class.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this but I'm not in love with the implementation.

On Master Page:

```
...
            <c:Menu id="myMenu" runat="server" />
            ...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script runat="server">
    public bool IsConsumerNavVisible
    {
        set
        {
            myMenu.Visible = value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

On PageLayout:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = Page.Master.GetType().GetProperty("IsConsumerNavVisible");
        pi.SetValue(Page.Master, false, null);
    }
</script>
```

So I exposed a public property on the master page to set the visibility and then used reflection on the PageLayout to find & set that property. I tried putting the PageLayout code in just a <% %> script block and it executed but the menu would end up visible anyway. Putting it in a Page_Load event handler fixed that. If there is a better way I'm all ears.